# Topology of a specific shape

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups

How to find topology of this shape?
It's Fundamental group, homotopy type and some interesting information about it?

[image: Shape]

Comment: Um, it seems to be vaguely similar to the edges of a [rhombic triacontahedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron), except all twisted. (That solid has 32 vertices; 20 of degree three and 12 of degree five.)

Comment: I'm guessing that, as a surface, it's probably a torus of genus 29 (one fewer than the number of faces of the rhombic triacontahedron — "triaconta-" means 30).

Comment: My first thought would be to see if you can write down the shape as a graph. Since the graph is related to the surface by a deformation retraction, the two are homotopy equivalent. Computing the fundamental group of the graph is then a straightforward (but messy!) procedure.

Comment: @MarkB Are you sure? This surface seems to be related to the graph the same way a torus is related to a circle. I'm pretty sure that the circle isn't a deformation retract of the torus.

Comment: I'm very curious as to where this surface came from.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger That would depend on whether this object is supposed to be hollow or not, which is not clear from the picture or the question. If the object is not hollow, then I think Mark B.'s suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: @vejn Could you give some more details about this shape? With only this picture I don't think there is much interesting to be said about it.

Comment: I created it in Wings 3D program. I started as icosahedron and then beveled the vertices, connected the faces and twisted it. Handles are similar as torus cut. @MarkB , how to define a graph of this object?

Comment: @MarcPaul , object is hollow as torus.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger , why did you say that genus is one fewer than the number of faces of the rhombic triacontahedron? How did we come to that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe the continuous transformation…

Comment: Um, project the edges of the 30hedron onto a sphere, and then use stereographic projection to project the edges onto a plane. The boundary of a small neighborhood of the edges (that is, the torus-like thing surrounded those edges) should be homeomorphic to the original surface, and I think it would have 29 holes (one for each face, not counting the face that got projected to the outside in the stereographic projection). I hope that was coherent.

Comment: It's only a subdivision of edges. I think that doesn't change topology. @AkivaWeinberger could you suggest a reading about these findings. I would like to learn it more.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I had assumed it was a solid shape. If it's hollow then my suggestion won't work.

Comment: It's hollow as a sphere but closed also.